# Try to connect Twilio Studio with Flex

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio, twilio-flex

I'm trying to connect a conversation flow via WhatsApp to Flex following the steps in this link https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/setup/conversations/manage-conversations-whatsapp-addresses#configuring-whatsapp-sandbox

The created function even works, but nothing happens in flex, the conversation is simply not added. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? or what if something is missing? I appreciate if anyone can help.

[flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6U88.png)
[funtion working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUnXO.png)